# IE 8 - 9 Conditional Stylesheet not triggering

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I've added the following to get IE8 and IE9 to use my ie8.css but doesn't seem to be using it at all when I emulate being on IE8 or IE9. (Don't have them installed so I am using IE11 developer tools to do this as normal.)

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php HTTP_HOST; ?>/Styles/global-en.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<!--<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php HTTP_HOST; ?>/Styles/ie8.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php HTTP_HOST; ?>/Styles/ie8.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<![endif]-->
```

Live URL: http://bit.ly/1r4dvw5

Comment: Never rely on IE's compatibility mode to give you an accurate representation of how earlier IE versions will actually work. If you want to see how it will work in IE8, then you have to use a real copy of IE8; that's all there is to it. Use a VM for this. Its the only truly reliable way.

Answer (score 1):

The emulator of IE11 is abit screwed up, check this post:
http://www.impressivewebs.com/ie11-emulation-conditional-comments/

What i would suggest is to install something like IEtester:
http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Or for a better experience install VM's via http://www.modern.ie